# Flask, jinja2 and bootstrap. Change grid columns based on breakpoints

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to using flask and I struggled with creating clean grid layout when looping through a dictionary of values (Will eventually be a database). I found a solution that works pretty well (Using a batch filter), but it doesn't work as well as I want it to

Right now it looks good at full size screen, but when the browser window gets smaller it reformats to 1 column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi9ZZ.jpg)

How do I make the grid change to 2 columns at a certain breakpoint?
Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid justify-content-start">
    {% for row in db | batch(4) %}
        <div class="row align-items-start">
        {% for column in row %}
            <div class="col-md-3 p-2">
                <div class="card" style="max-width: fit-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img class="card-img-top" style="max-width: 300px" src="{{ column.img }}" alt="{{ column.name }}.img">
                        <h5 class="card-title" href="/">{{ column.name }}</h5>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary stretched-link" href="/services">Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```